# WP database error for comments_popup_link()

Tags: php, database, mysql, query

I'm using the `comments_popup_link()` function to show the number of comments for each post in a loop.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>

<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb_value', true) ) : ?>
        //something
<?php else: ?>
       //something else
<?php endif; ?>


        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 

        <?php the_content(__('Read more'));?>
        <div class="post-meta">
       <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
       <p>Category: <?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
       <p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
       <p><?php comments_popup_link('Post Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?></p>      
    </div>


<?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php $wpdb->show_errors(); 
$wpdb->print_error(); ?>

<?php else: ?>

<p><strong>There has been an error.</strong></p>
<?php $wpdb->show_errors(); ?> 
<?php $wpdb->print_error(); ?> </p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Everything displays fine but I get

> WordPress database error: [] SELECT *
>   FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID
>   = 216 AND comment_approved = '1' ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC

I'm just curios why I get that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your template code includes `$wpdb->print_error()`. This function prints the last database error between `[` and `]` brackets, and the executed SQL code. But if there is no error, you just see the empty brackets and the SQL.

`$wpdb->show_errors()` is used to [enable displaying of database errors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#Show_and_Hide_SQL_Errors). If you want to see all database errors, you can just call this function somewhere higher in your code (in your `functions.php`, or in a plugin). You probably only want to do this when you are in debug mode, so it would look like this:

```
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    $wpdb->show_errors();
}
```

Comment: Oooh! Thank you for explaining :) I really concerned. lol